# How to set https to off mode for KeyCloak?

Tags: https, keycloak

From here I found that 2 commands for that:
https://www.keycloak.org/docs/4.8/server_admin/

```
kcadm.sh config credentials --server http://[IPv6 here]:8080/auth --realm master --user admin
kcadm.sh update realms/realmname -s sslRequired=NONE
```

But after run the first command it got:

```
HTTPS required [invalid_request]
```

Comment: I would use doc related to your used Keycloak version. `4.8` seems to be very old. Current Keycloak is `8.0`.

Comment: It seems you have to run the command as https - `https://[IPv6 here]:8080/auth ` before you switched it off.

Comment: @YuriyP I don't have a certification yet.